# Pipeline command for windows in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, scheduled-tasks

In linux we use "popen3","open3","capture3" gem  to run a commands in a command prompt from running ruby file itself.

In windows, what and how to use to run a command in a command prompt without opening a command prompt of windows.By running ruby file have to execute those commands in command prompt .

Also can anybody explain about io/console and popen4.

Thanks,
indra

Comment: have you tried `\`` backticks

Comment: i ve used spawn process to execute a command in command prompt of windows